# The usefulness of java util classes to call a service (to create a model) as opposed to using that services's impl

Tags: java, object-oriented-design, api, api-design, utilities

#### Example

I will explain the paradigm below but I am specifically talking about Liferay's Service Builder code for anyone who knows that platform.

Basically in Liferay you can definite a model and it's properties in an xml file.  Let's say that we have a Student entity with the following properties: studentId, name, age, grade, gender.  From that model Liferay builds the following classes

- Student (interface for the model)
- StudentImpl
- StudentService (interface for the service)
- StudentServiceImpl
- StudentServiceUtil

In the StudentSericeImpl class you can write the implementation for any methods you want int your StudentService class.  So let's say we have the following interface:

```
interface StudentService {
   public Student createStudent(String name, int age, double grade, boolean gender);
   public Student getStudent(long studentId);
}
```

Then your StudentLocalServiceImpl would implement those methods.  However in your code you would never initialize your service or create a model like this.

```
StudentService studentService = new StudentServiceImpl() 
Student chris = studentService.createStudent("chris", 27, 36.23, false);
```

Instead you would use the util class.

```
Student chris = StudentServiceUtil.createStudent("chris", 27, 36.23, false);
```

You can then also implement the `StudentService` class in a few other ways.  For example, you can create a `StudentServiceSoap` for remote use of a SOAP service.

Do you think this util class is useful, and if so for what reasons?

Comment: Is `StudentServiceUtil` a simple to use ioc-free singelton implementation using a `static StudentService studentService = new StudentServiceImpl() ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think this is good design.

The objects that need to use `StudentService` should have one injected. They should not themselves use a singleton-style interface like `StudentServiceUtil`. Here are a few reasons why:

- If you're using this `StudentServiceUtil`, how can you configure two objects to use different instances of `StudentService`?
- How can you unit-test the code that uses `StudentServiceUtil`? It's better to inject the interface, `StudentService` that you can mock directly.
- The dependency on `StudentService` will be hidden if you use `StudentServiceUtil`. It won't be apparent that a class may change or fetch from the `StudentService` without inspection of the implementation.